# Binding Does not Commit?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a `TabControl` bound to a `ICollectionView` with derives from `ObservableCollection<EditorTabViewModel>`. I think quite standard MVVM Multi-Document pattern? Anyways, `EditorTabViewModel` has a property `Content` that contains the string to be displayed. I find that the binding is working ...

```
// Add 2 default tabs for a test, also set their Content property to the respective values ...
_tabs.Add(new EditorTabViewModel { Content = "Tab 1" });
_tabs.Add(new EditorTabViewModel { Content = "Tab 2" });
```

Its values are correctly rendered

**XAML**

```
<!-- DataTemplate to render EditorTabViewModels -->
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:EditorTabViewModel}">
    <me:MarkdownEditor 
        TextContent="{Binding Path=Content.Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        Options="{Binding Path=Options, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

**Result**

[image]

But when I change the value, switch tabs and return, I get the string set in the constructor again ... shown in **[this video (on screenr)](http://screenr.com/oQc)**

The **[Visual Studio Solution](http://www.mediafire.com/?ahk686k44vsxuc9)**

Comment: Mediafire doesn't allow me to download the sources. Presumably because lots of people from my region are trying to download something from it at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged for the TextBox "txtEditor" in MarkdownEditor.xaml. Default UpdateSourceTrigger value for a TextBox is LostFocus and that event is never raised when changing tab. That's why it reverts back to the previous value

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="txtEditor" AcceptsReturn="True"
         Text="{Binding TextContent, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
         FontFamily="{Binding Path=Options.FontFamily}"
         FontSize="{Binding Path=Options.FontSize}"
         FontWeight="{Binding Path=Options.FontWeight}"
         Background="{Binding Path=Options.Background}"
         Foreground="{Binding Path=Options.Foreground}" />
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure, but this solution may lead to high memory consumption. You are going to allocate a new string on every text change in the `txtEditor`. For short texts it's affordable, but not for document editor. It's better to hook to LostFocus event or something.

Comment: @alpha-mouse Because of the way the .NET garbage collector works, creating large (vast!) numbers of small short-lived objects, like strings, is rarely a problem.

Comment: @Bevan: We are speaking about text editor here. So these strings are not going to be especially _small_.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: I think you missunderstood the problem to begin with. Default `UpdateSourceTrigger` for the Text Property of a `TextBox` is `LostFocus`. However, that event was never raised when changing tabs directly so the source was never updated. Also, I tried inserting and working with insainly HUGE text amounts in that TextBox and I couldn't notice any difference in either performance or memory consumption between `LostFocus` and `PropertyChanged`

Comment: @alpha-mouse From the perspective of the garbage collector, the threshold for "small" is a pretty large string. 87KB, if memory serves. That's a pretty sizable piece of text. Still, you make a good point - working with multi-megabyte strings is a good way to create a lot of memory pressure.

Comment: @Bevan: I agree, `LostFocus` is preferable (and that's why it is the default value). However, you can't use that if `LostFocus` is never raised :) Either find a workaround for the bug in the Framework for when a TextBox is focused and the current Tab is changed, or change `UpdateSourceTrigger`

Answer (score 0):

I'll suppose that `MarkdownEditor.TextContent` property doesn't tell anyone that it's value is changed, so binding mechanism doesn't bother to write it's new value to `EditorTabViewModel.Content`. If `TextContent` is a dependency property of `MarkdownEditor` can you ensure that it receives changed text from the control you are using to actually edit text (`TextBox` or something)?